# Windows Service Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, windows-services

I have a windows service to get data from remote Database to update local. For each get operation i am writing a log file with information (errors, success) for review.

However the data is so huge that sometimes, Service is using up RAM on the server and hence crashing it :(. I understand there is a memory leak, I am unable to spot it though. However, in my initial analysis I figured out that the memory leak might be in how I am writing to the log. Here is a short explanation of what i am doing.

I have a Utility "STATIC" class with a method to write entries to log.

```
private static readonly object syncObj = new object(); //Class scope property

private static void Log()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("c:/test.txt", true))
        {
           sw.WriteLine("message");
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called number of times to log file entries. I am unable to understand where the memory is leaking and how to fill the leak.

1. Is it the Static class with static method in it (where i cannot use the IDisposable) [this i am not sure as i am already writing the using clause to limit the scope which internally does that anyways.]
2. Is it the streamwriter which i am not sure, should i replace it with File.AppendAllText(path, message)?
3. Is it the lock which i am using inefficiently?

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: This looks OK to me and I believe that none of your 3 points should be a problem. What makes you think that this code causes memory problems? Have you tried commenting it out to see if your program works better without it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its tough for me replicate the scenario in local. However the SAT environment shows this behavior. The reason why i say its a memory issue is because on server i see the service use up at-least 1.5 to 2 Gigs and only increasing memory. I do not understand why it should use that much memory and also when we stop this service the server memory looks alright. The problem part is however when the server crashes :(.

I do not have any other piece of code apart from File operation which i think might give problems.

Comment: None of the code for logging you have posted will cause a memory leak. Thus the issue must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I think you are right, i identified something in my code to see if that is causing problem(s). Will come back with a reply once i am done analyzing.